# How do I avoid rounding errors with doubles?

Tags: java, math, double, rounding

I'm using Math.sin to calculate trigonometry in Java with 3 decimal precision. However when I calculate values that should result in an Integer I get 1.0000000002 instead of 1.

I have tried using

```
 System.out.printf(Locale.ROOT, "%.3f ", v);
```

which does solve the problem of *1.000000002* turning into *1.000.*

However when I calculate numbers that should result in *0* and instead get *-1.8369701987210297E-16* and use

```
  System.out.printf(Locale.ROOT, "%.3f ", v);
```

prints out -0.000 when I need it to be 0.000.

Any ideas on how to get rid of that negative sign?

Comment: It looks like printf() doesn't provide an option for that. Honestly I'd just check if `Math.abs(v) < 0.001` and set v to 0.0 or just display 0.000 if it is.

Comment: You  can do `Math.round(v * 1000d) / 1000d` to round the number first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets start with this:

> How do I avoid rounding errors with doubles?

Basically, you can't.  They are inherent to numerical calculations using floating point types.  Trust me ... or take the time to read this article:

- [What every Computer Scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) by David Goldberg.

In this case, the other thing that comes into play is that trigonometric functions are implemented by computing a finite number of steps of an infinite series with finite precision (i.e. floating point) arithmetic.  The javadoc for the `Math` class leaves some "wiggle room" on the accuracy of the math functions.  It is worth reading the javadocs to understand the *expected* error bounds.

Finally, if you are computing (for example) *sin π/2* you need to consider how accurate your representation of *π/2* is.

---

So what you should really be asking is how to *deal with* the rounding error that unavoidably happens.

In this case, you are asking is how to make it look like the user of your program as if there isn't any rounding error.   There are two approaches to this:

- Leave it alone!  The rounding errors occur, so we should not lie to the users about it.  It is better to educate them.  (Honestly, this is *high school* maths, and even "the pointy haired boss" should understand that arithmetic is inexact.)

  Routines like `printf` do a pretty good job.  And the -0.000 displayed in this case is actually a truthful answer.  It means that the computed answer rounds to zero to 3 decimal places but is actually negative.  This is not actually hard for someone with high school maths to understand.  If you explain it.
- Lie.  Fake it.  Put in some special case code to explicitly convert numbers between -0.0005 and zero to exactly zero.  The code suggested in a comment

  ```
    System.out.printf(Locale.ROOT, "%.3f ", Math.round(v * 1000d) / 1000d);
  ```

  is another way to do the job.  But the risk of this is that the lie could be dangerous in some circumstances.  On the other hand, you could say that real mistake problem is displaying the numbers to 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on accuracy you need, you can multiply by `X` and divide by `X` where X is `X=10^y` and y is required floating poing precision.